# Python command line UI

Tags: python, command-line, user-interface

Hey guys/gals I'm writing a python script that fixes some duplicate issues on my database. I would like to display some progress status to the users, currently I just print it like this:

```
print "Merged " + str(idx) + " out of " + str(totalCount);
```

The problem is that it prints that in a new line for every record and that does not look so good :) I'd like to either always print the string above on the same line on the screen or use some smart widget that displays it in some sort of progress bar.

I intent to run this on the command line, any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to constantly overwrite the same line, use `'\r'` and `print foo,` to act as a carriage return and a non-endline-printing `print`.

```
while doingStuff:
    msg = "\rMerged %s out of %s" % (idx, totalCount)
    print msg,
```

But if you're designing a fancier console app, you maybe should look into using [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) (only for Unix though)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`fish`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fish/).

Comment: +1 for "The default fish is a simple bass at a pretty good velocity for an ASCII fish."

Comment: Thx, fish looks pretty kewl. I'm marking @Daniel DiPaolo question as the answer because that is what I will use since I don't wanna add the fish dependency to my little script. But Thx very much for the help!